# Connection issues even after I opened the port on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: tcp, sphinx, ports

I am trying to connect through port 3312 from one EC2 instance to another.

On the one receiving the inbound connection I opened TCP port 3312 for my web server's IP but alas it gives me when I try to connect:

Query failed: connection to 23.21.134.185:3312 failed (errno=111, msg=Connection refused).

I am trying to access a sphinx search index on the server I am trying to connect to....beyond amazon's firewall what do I have to do to let sphinx work through this port as needed?

Comment: Can you connect from another machine on the same "lan" (ie any other machine than localhost)?

Comment: I can connect on other ports fine, i.e. mysql 3306. I am thinking it has to be a sphinx specific issue, but I am a little lost.

Comment: Check the listen directive in sphinx.conf, if it says "localhost:3312" or similar, sphinx is only listening to requests from the local machine. Check this for details; http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-listen

Comment: I think I am getting sphinx all mixed up...if i already have create an index on server B do I need to install the searchd on server A? If so then what needs to be running on server B beyond the index?

Comment: You only need searchd installed on the server running the actual daemon. the client machines dont need sphinx installed. They just need the relevent client library.